# Is this integral correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, special-functions

I used substitution and got that:
$$\int_0^\pi \sin x \cdot P_n(\cos x ) \, dx=0$$
where $P_n$ is the $n$-th Legendre polynomial.

Comment: What integral you were calculating?

Comment: Are you calculating $\int_{-1}^{1}P_0(t)P_n(t)dt $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that Legendre polynomials are defined as orthogonal polynomials on $[-1,1]$ with weight function $w(x)=1$. In other words, we have by definition
$$(P_m,P_n)=\int_{-1}^1P_m(x)P_n(x)dx\sim \delta_{mn}.$$
But, since $P_0(x)=1$, your integral is equal to $(P_0,P_n)$ and therefore it vanishes whenever $n>0$. For $n=0$, however, it is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you, but why is it equal to 2, I mean if my integral is $(P_0,P_n)$ then it should be equal to 1, as $(P_0,P_0)=1$ is the only one that survives?

Comment: @Lipschitz Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, not orthonormal.

Comment: you are right, sorry! thank you very much

Comment: @Lipschitz You are welcome! In fact, in front of the Kronecker symbol there is a factor $2/(2n+1)$. But here you don't even need to know it, just integrate $1$ from $-1$ to $1$. Of course, the result will reproduce $2/(2\cdot 0+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Power reduction formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) for the cosine, you see that all monomials in your Legendre polynomial involve only cosines of integer multiples of $x$. These are odd functions on the interval $[0,\pi]$ while the sine function is even, thus their product must be odd and the integral is zero.

Comment: I think the oddness is not quite true: e.g. $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$.